# can't pass right method and the controller to angular js module ng-submit

Tags: java, angularjs, mongodb, spring-boot

I am developing a new library management software with spring boot,angular js, and MongoDB as backend. I want to perform crud operation  on MongoDB with that application and for that I referring some open source project with that I can perform create and read operations successfully but can't perform delete and update operations so how can perform  I also made some changes for delete update but can't perform with that so tell me the changes have to perform in order to perform delete.I added this as my own in mybooks.html but the element is not deleting.for that made some changes in mybooks.html and hello.js for delete operation but the element is not deleting

```
<td><form ng-submit="controller.delete()">
  <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Delete">
        </div>
</form></td>
```

bookrestcontroller.java

```
package com.sezin.controller;

import com.sezin.model.Book;
import com.sezin.repository.BookRepository;
import com.sezin.repository.UserAccountRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.RequestConditionHolder;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by sezin on 3/23/16.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/books")
public class BookRestController {

    @Autowired
    BookRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Book> getAllBooks(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getByTitle/{title}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Book getBookByTitle(@PathVariable String title){
        return repository.findByTitle(title);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getByAuthor/{author}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Book> getBooksByAuthor(@PathVariable String author){
        return repository.findByAuthor(author);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/getAll/{userName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Book> getBooksByUserName(@PathVariable String userName){
        return repository.findByUserName(userName);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value ="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Book create(@RequestBody Book book){
        if( userAccountRepository.findByUsername(book.getUserName()) != null &&
                repository.findByTitle(book.getTitle()) == null){
            return repository.save(book);
        }
        else
            return null;

    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable String id){


        repository.delete(id);



    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "{id}")
    public Book update(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Book book){
        Book updated = repository.findOne(id);
        updated.setAuthor(book.getAuthor());
        updated.setTitle(book.getTitle());
        updated.setYear(book.getyear());
        return repository.save(book);

    }
}
```

securitycontroller.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   /* http
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/", "/register.html", "/account").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);*/
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/", "/register.html", "/account", "/api","/delete").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().
            httpBasic().and().
            csrf().disable();

}
```

mybooks.html

```
  <tr>
      <th>BooK_id</th>
    <th>BooK_title</th>
    <th>BooK_author</th>        
    <th>BooK_year</th>
    <th>update</th>
 </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="message in controller.messages">
    <td>{{message.id}}</td>
    <td>{{message.title}}</td>
    <td>{{message.author}}</td>     
    <td>{{message.year}}</td>
    <td><form ng-submit="remove(message.id)" ng-controller="books">
  <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Delete">
        </div>
</form></td>
 </tr>
```

hello.js

```
  /**
 * Created by sezin on 3/22/16.
 */
angular.module('hello', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngCookies'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'home.html',
            controller : 'home',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }).when('/login', {
            templateUrl : 'login.html',
            controller : 'navigation',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }).when('/register', {
            templateUrl : 'register.html',
            controller : 'register',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }).when('/mybooks', {
            templateUrl : 'mybooks.html',
            controller : 'books',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }).otherwise('/'); 

        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

    })
    .controller('home', function($http, $cookies) {
        var self = this;
        $http.get('/resource/').success(function(data){
            self.greeting = data;

            self.currentUserName = $cookies.get("username");

            //self.messages = [];
            self.saveBook = function(){
                //var BookRecord = $resource('/account/', {username : self.currentUserName});
                //BookRecord.save(self.book);
                var request = {
                    userName: self.currentUserName,
                    title: self.book.title,
                    author: self.book.author,
                    year: self.book.year
                };
                $http.post('api/books/add', request).success(function(data){

                    if(data){
                        self.success = true;
                    } if(data == null){
                        self.success = false;
                    }
                    console.log(data);
                    //self.messages.push({type:'success', msg: 'Book Saved!'});
                }). error(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                });
            };






        });


    })
    .controller('books', function($http, $cookies){
        var self = this;
        self.messages = [];
        self.currentUserName = $cookies.get("username");
        $http.get('api/books/getAll/' + self.currentUserName).success(function(data){

            self.messages = data;
            console.log(data);
        });

        self.remove = function(messageId){

$http.delete('messageId');


};


})
    .controller('navigation', function($rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies) {
        var self = this;
        var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {
            var headers = credentials ? {authorization: "Basic "
            + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)} :{};

            $http.get('/user/', {headers : headers}).success(function(data){
                if(data.name){
                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                    $rootScope.username = data.username;
                    if (typeof callback == "function") {
                        callback() && callback();
                    }

                } else{
                    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                    if (typeof callback == "function") {
                        callback() && callback();
                    }
                }
            })
        };

        authenticate();
        self.credentials = {};
        self.login = function(){
            authenticate(self.credentials, function () {
                if($rootScope.authenticated){
                    $location.path("/");
                    $rootScope.username = self.credentials.username;
                    $cookies.put("username", $rootScope.username);
                    self.error = false;
                } else{
                    $location.path("/login");
                    self.error = true;
                }

            });
        };

        self.logout = function(){
            $http.post('logout', {}).finally(function(){
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                $location.path("/");
            });
        }
    })
    .controller('register', function($resource, $rootScope, $location){
        var self = this;
        self.register = function(){
            var User = $resource('/account');
            User.save(self.user, function(data){
                    self.success = data;


            });
        };

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to use double curly brackets on angular directives

Update

```
<form ng-submit="remove({{message.id}}" ng-controller="books">
```

to

```
<form ng-submit="remove(message.id)" ng-controller="books">
```

Also your `controller function` in `books` doesn't take a parameter

```
self.remove = function(){
    $http.delete('id');
};
```

Should update it also

```
self.remove = function(messageId){
    // Perform the delete
};
```

Comment: what code I have to write for delete ?  not working please go step further

Comment: @Ydworld I would say if would be something like `$http.delete('/api/books/' + messageId)`. Also I would change your delete form to a simple button: `<input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" value="Delete" ng-click="remove(message.id)">`

Comment: hello can we have discussion please

Comment: not working I had already given you project link can you perform delete operation in that tell me exactly what I to do

Comment: have look at this question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/q/49382487/4356983 help me if you can

Comment: have look at this problem stackoverflow.com/q/48429456/4356983